# I created a static NAT internal -> public and internal -> internal. What did I do exactly that made this work?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, vmware-esxi

I have two windows VM's on the same host with IIS and they're both connected to a cisco firewall. I gave each VM a static nat rule for internal -> public with their respective dedicated IP's and it's able to travel the internet using the public IP I gave it.

The two servers however aren't able to visit the websites hosted on each other. I used to have to change the hosts file for them to communicate.

I then played around and put an internal -> internal NAT and they started communicating without the hosts file being edited.

Can anyone explain what happened?

When server 1 visits a website on server 2, does it now visit the server with the public IP i gave it? or did some other magic happen?

If they ping each other, they still show internal IP as the result ip. Was the NAT the correct fix, or should I have changed something inside IIS to work instead?